# Google Classroom not returning classmates even with permission

Tags: python, google-classroom

I'm trying to use the following api call to get a student's classmates:

https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list

The classmates are visible when I login to google classroom as the student I'm authenticated with and look at the "classmates" tab for a class, however the api call is only returning 1 student, my own student that I'm logged in as.

I have permission for all the scopes, including these ones:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly
```

Comment: Strange. I'm also having this issue. Maybe google do this purposely? So we can't make "clone apps"

Comment: One option left, is to find out, how does Google's Classroom app get that info